# Regex match everything after a character in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet and want to remove everything after [

somebody told me to use this

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"(.*)\[.*","$1")
```

the problem is if a string has no [ it throws an error and if there are multiple [ only everything after the last one is removed

Comment: You need to be more specific. For example, what should happen in a case like this: xxx[yyy]xxx[yyy]xxx? Do you want to delete everything after the first [ so the result would be xxx or do you want to delete everything after each [ sign but keep the rest after the closing ] sign like this: xxxxxxxxx?

Comment: Please illustrate with some realistic raw data and what you expect the return to be for each. (Better yet, share a link to a sample spreadsheet illustrating this.)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my understanding, this is the formula you're looking for:

```
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E231,"([^[.*]+)\["))
```

Instead of using `REGEXREPLACE` which finds a regex pattern and replaces it with something else, I used `REGEXEXTRACT` which locates a regex pattern and extracts it.

`.*` = any character except newline

`[.*]+` = mach one or more occurrences of "any character"

`([^[.*]+)` = `^` begin match from left-to-right, `()` focus only on what is inside

`([^[.*]+)\[` = stop the match at the first `[` (not including)

I've added the `IFNA` function to avoid getting #N/A messages whenever there is no `[` present.